# Ensure that parametric type has companion object

Tags: scala, companion-object

I'd like to do something like this (and please, don't ask why):

```
trait A[T /* tell that there exists companion for T */] {
    def f = T.g
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box. You'll have to use a macro based solution. I happen to have published [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Jasper-M/1b6540fecfa3af9094dab1614038a1b5) of such a solution a while ago.

You could use it like this:

```
def getCompanion[T: HasCompanion] = HasCompanion[T].companion
```

However you can't use context bounds on the type parameter of a trait.